# Transactional for multiple tables

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to add the transactional to the multiple tables , that simply means even if the data entry in one of the tables fail the transaction should not affect other tables. However , I have gone through spring boot tutorial :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

But this talks only about single table. I have tables which are not even engaged using foreign keys.

I am using jdbctemplate for connecting with the database.

Comment: Transactions are not about tables. Transactions are about executing multiple statements, whatever the table they use, as an atomic operation. If you want an insert into B to faikl without rollbacking a previous insert into A, then the insert into A should be executed in a different transaction than the insert into B.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have updated the question , I am passing on the different queries to my method , which updates/inserts the multiple tables , I pass on the queries, I would like to make this method as a single transaction.

Comment: Make up your mind. In your question, you're saying that a failure to insert in one table should not affect the inserts in other tables (at least, that's what I understood). Now you're saying that all the inserts should be done in a single transaction. Both are contradictory. What do you **really** want? A transaction means that, if something fails and the transaction is rollbacked, then everything that happened in the transaction is rollbacked, i.e. everything goes back as if you didn't execute any statement.

Comment: I want a method where in I will pass multiple sql queries using jdbctemplate , Even if single query fails while iterating , transaction should roll back

Comment: So, annotate your bean method with @Transactional, as explained in the documentation. What is the problem?

Comment: Even after trying @Transactional it is rolling back for the table 1.

Comment: For testing it I am applying some rules on table2 for example adding the not null constraint , so that insertion in table 2 would fail , insertion in table 2 fails but it inserts into the table1

Comment: That's just what you asked: *if single query fails while iterating , transaction should roll back*. So it behaves as you just said you wanted it to behave. I repeat, if you don't want that, then you need to do your inserts in table A in a first transaction, and your inserts in table B in a second, different transaction. But most importantly, you need to stopt coding, and start reading about what a transaction is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114457/discussion-between-chetan-and-jb-nizet).